# Best solution to protect the floor while painting the walls

Tags: paint

For painting work I usually protect the floor using big sheets (like 4 x 4 meters) of transparent plastic sold in Asda that I spread around the room.

However it can move a lot while I walk on it and then there are spaces left exposed. Also it's not very flat.

Ideally I'd like something which covers 100% of the floor 100% of the time while being as flat as possible. Is there such a solution?

Comment: old newspapers and masking tape

Comment: Have you tried taping the joints of the plastic sheets to form one large sheet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Drop Cloths

The most common solution, is to use canvas drop cloths. This has been the choice of the pros for many, many years.

[image: Canvas Drop Cloth]

## Heavy Paper

36 mil paper is a common choice when working over hard flooring. It provides good spill protection, while also providing a bit of added drop protection.

[image: Ram Board]

## Masonite Sheets

In higher end homes, where flooring can be quite expensive (and may be installed before construction is completed). 1/8" - 1/4" [Masonite sheets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masonite) can be laid over a [medium weight or Rosin paper](http://www.trimaco.com/paper.php), to provide good spill and drop protection.

[image]

Comment: For a newly refinished floor, a canvas drop cloth is best.  Most floor supply stores will suggest never applying *any* kind of tape on a new finish, since you can ruin it.

Answer (score 4):

Many contractors and painters use **[rosin paper](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Trimaco-36-in-x-167-ft-Red-Rosin-Medium-Weight-Paper-35145/202040751#.Up3TKsRDsTY)** as a floor barrier. It comes in long rolls.

[image: rosin paper]

This paper protects against most spills and scratches. It also is not very slick, so it doesn't slide around. It is only 3 feet wide, so it is put down in strips and then taped together using masking tape.

The edges are also often taped up to baseboards or cabinetry to make a clean painting line, but use special edge tape if you want a very sharp line.

Painters also use canvas drop clothes which are heavy duty and reusable, but much more expensive.

Comment: When I use rosen paper on the floor I roll out the strips so they overlap some and then tape them together. This is opposed to trying to place the strips side by side.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Absolutely! I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 2):

After years of struggling with newspapers or plastic sheets I came to a simple solutions that works great for painting walls: I place the paint bucket over a flattened large cardboard box (roughly 1X1 meter. Any other stiff material can work). I push the cardboard right against the wall I am painting, and for each new section (most often after each roller dip in the paint bucket) I move it along the wall (by about 30-50 CM). This way you don't need to prep the floor cover but still have something to protect the floor as you paint.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pre-taped masking film covering floor for painting. Thus can solve your problem.
[image]
Pre-taped masking films one side has adhesive tapes, You can use adhesive tape on the floor, then open the plastic film. If one pre-tape masking film cannot cover the whole floor, you can use another to cover with pasting the previous, till the whole floor is covered.

The pre-taped masking films can cut into certain shape by scissors, which can meet your need.
[image]

Due to adhesive on the floor, so it cannot move when you work and there is no space left exposed. After using, only reveal it.